# A test that verifies if an imported function (that is a dependency of an adapter) is called with correct parameters in the adapter using Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

My test is like this

```
import { SlugGeneratorAdapter } from './slug-generator-adapter'
import slugify from 'slugify'

describe('SlugGenerator Adapter', () => {
  test('Deve chamar slug generator com os parâmetros corretos. ', () => {
    const target = new SlugGeneratorAdapter()

    const slugifySpy = jest.fn(slugify)

    target.gerar('any text')
    expect(slugifySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('any text')
  }

  )
})
```

my other relevant class is like this

```
import slugify from 'slugify'
import { SlugGenerator } from '../../data/protocols/slug-generator'

export class SlugGeneratorAdapter implements SlugGenerator {
  gerar (param: string): string {
    slugify(param)
    return 'any_value'
  }
}
```

I just don't have enough jest knowlege to implement this test. It's failing because slugify is never called (I believe). For those that don't know slugify is function that add slashes to string

you can do this

```
 import slugify from 'slugify'

 slugify('any text more text') it returns // any-text-more-text
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `jest.spyOn`, which expects an object and a method name, so if you want to spy on the `default` member, you can try

```
import * as slugify from 'slugify'
const slugifySpy = jest.spyOn(slugify, 'default')

// ... act ...
expect(slugyfySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('....')
```